# Printing string array to txt file

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am new to programming but I like it and I am trying to learn as much as possible.
I am coding a small application that has a multiline text box (txtOutput) where I input my comments. These comments/lines are then transferred in an array of strings.
I then call a class transferring some variable and also the array to print all out to a txt file.
While I can get the txt file populated with the data from the variables, I cannot get the content of the array to the txt file. I would appreciate some help.

**Text from txtOutput to array**

```
public void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string[] comments = txtOutput.Text.Split(' ');
```

**Transfer of array** and other variables to class1 (where I have the code to create and save the content of those variables and the array to txt file). The other two variables are printed out on the file without problems.

```
WriteTextFile WTR = new WriteTextFile();
        WTR.Save(temperatura, speedMotore, comments);
```

**Class1 code (where I do make the txt file and save it.**

```
class WriteTextFile
{
    public void Save(int sendTem, int sendMot, string[] comments)
    {
        DateTime Now = DateTime.Now;
        string dateTime = Now.ToString("F");
        SaveFileDialog sd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sd.Filter = "Text File | *.txt";
        if (sd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)  
{  
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sd.FileName))  
{
    sw.Write("File diconfigurazione del programma Arduino Control " + "\r\n");
    sw.Write("\r\n");
    sw.Write(dateTime + "\r\n");
    sw.Write("\r\n");
    sw.Write("\r\n");
    sw.Write("La temperatura impostata in PWM1 è: " + sendMot + "\r\n");
    sw.Write("\r\n");
    sw.Write("La velocità del motore impostata in PWM2 è: " + sendTem + "\r\n");
    sw.Write("\r\n");
    sw.Write(comments[1] + "\r\n");
    sw.Dispose();  
    sw.Close();
}  


}}}
```

I am not sure if I am transferring any text from the txtOutput to the "comments" array correctly. What I would like to achieve is to get those lines from the txtOutput printed on the txt file one by one and instead I just receive a message that says "Index out of range......."

Comment: Your array index starts at zero - I suspect `comments[0]` instead of `comments[1]` might do the trick.

Comment: You use `sw.Write` and every time you add the string `"\r\n"`. It is easier and more clear to use `sw.WriteLine` instead. You don't have to use `sw.Dispose()` and `sw.Close()` because you have put the `sw` into a `using` block (like you must). The "index out of range" you get, comes from the array access `comments[1]`. Check `comments.Length`. The index inside the `[ ... ]` starts at zero and ends at length _minus one_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Thank you all for your comments.
The array in my program works like this:

```
string[] comments = textBox5.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

then to print the content:

```
foreach (string i in comments)
{
sw.Write(i + "\r\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not call `Dispose` as you do inside the `using` statement - the `using` statement will take care of that. This is likely the cause of the problem - the stream would dispose before flushing.

Just keep:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sd.FileName))  
{
    sw.Write("File diconfigurazione del programma Arduino Control " + "\r\n");
    sw.Write("\r\n");
    sw.Write(dateTime + "\r\n");
    sw.Write("\r\n");
    sw.Write("\r\n");
    sw.Write("La temperatura impostata in PWM1 è: " + sendMot + "\r\n");
    sw.Write("\r\n");
    sw.Write("La velocità del motore impostata in PWM2 è: " + sendTem + "\r\n");
    sw.Write("\r\n");
    sw.Write(comments[1] + "\r\n");
    sw.Close();
}
```

Comment: I tried changing the index from 1 to 0, the result is no errors but nothing get printed out.

Comment: I tried to remove the sw.dispose but the error is still coming out.

Comment: @user2280374 - Did you debug through? From your description, `comments` is actually empty and has nothing it in, at least at the point that you call `Save`.

Comment: I have filled in 4 lines of text in the text box txtOutput

Comment: @user2280374 - Then why are you splitting by spaces? Shouldn't you be using `Environment.NewLine` instead?

Comment: @user2280374 as I said I am new to coding. Please give me an example. What would you change in my code?

Comment: `string[] comments = txtOutput.Text.Split(' ');` should probably be `string[] comments = txtOutput.Text.Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);` - your current code tries to split with spaces. New lines are not spaces.

Comment: I tried,i got the same error. If I change the index from 1 to 0 then no error but in any case nothing is printed out.

Comment: @user2280374 - I'll ask again - did you debug through the method? Did you check the values of the `comments` array? Did you check where you did `Split` to see if it puts anything in the array? Did you try to look at what you are splitting on? Debugging is essential for you here - I can't see what you have and not have, so you need to do this.

Comment: I did it now and the result is tha the value of comments is null

Comment: @user2280374 - That's what you need to fix then. Do you ever assign to it? Do you pass it in before it has been assigned to?

Comment: Sorry I cannot follow you. I think I assigned the content of the txtBox with the line of code "string[] comments = txtOutput.Text.Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);"

Comment: @user2280374 - Where did you do that? Before or after you called `Save`?

Comment: as you can see from my original code above, that gets done before I save and before I transfer such array to the class.

Comment: @user2280374 - Actually, I don't see that. You have posted separate code blocks and I am unwilling to make assumptions. Did you debug through to see if `comments` has a value after the `Split` line?

Comment: yes I did. The value of "comments" there is null. Then I replaced the original line of code "string[] comments = txtOutput.Text.Split(' '); with the one you suggested "string[] comments = txtOutput.Text.Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);" and I debugged. The result is that the array comments is null.

Comment: @user2280374 - And the value of `txtOutput.Text`? What's that?

Comment: Thanks a lot, your suggestion is correct, the line I replaced with the one you suggested "string[] comments = txtOutput.Text.Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);" associated with index 0 instead of 1 in the  stream writer section is giving me the correct result. Thanks for your help, really appreciated.